# feature extraction in OCR : any idea about these features?

Tags: image-processing, ocr

is there anyone who knows what are these features below, they are use in feature extraction level in OCR.

1. maximum number of absolute pixel difference of image in vertical scanning
2. maximum number of absolute pixel difference of image in horizontal scanning
3. Total Sum of absolute difference of successive pixels in image.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If ***I*** had these questions, and ***if*** neither Google nor the documentation of my OCR software would tell me what this could possibly mean, I'd start to reverse engineer it:

- Create a small set of simple bitmap images with 1, 2 and 3 rows of pixels (sizes '20x1', `20x2` and `20x3`;
- Create another small set of simple bitmap images with 1, 2 and 3 columns of pixels (sizes `1x20`, `2x20` and `3x20`);
- Colorize each of the pixels with different simple schemes;
- Find out what ImageMagick tells you about each Pixel's color values: `convert  20x1.png  20x1.txt`;
- Ask your OCR software what the mentioned features tell you about the sample pictures;
- Make your conclusions.